# The right way to singleton in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, singleton, httpcontext

Question: does the following code 100% ensures the uniqueness of the object per each user (which means per each browser (or request) as I understand)?

```
/// <summary>
        /// Ensures the uniqueness for each request. 
        /// </summary>
        private static MultiLanguageProvider Instance
        {
            get
            {
                var currentSession = HttpContext.Current.Session;
                var nameOfInstance = nameof(MultiLanguageProvider);

                if ((currentSession[nameOfInstance] as MultiLanguageProvider).IsNull())
                    currentSession[nameOfInstance] = new MultiLanguageProvider();

                return currentSession[nameOfInstance] as MultiLanguageProvider;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the documentation for [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This will be per browser.